# collection of variables in Z3 using C++ API

Tags: z3

I want to define a collection of variables like "x_1" ... "X_1000", using Z3 C++ API. Can this be done using a for loop? I mean something of the form :

```
expr x[100] ;
for( i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++)
{  sprintf(str, "x_%d", i);
   x[i] = c.bool_const(str);
}

solver s(c);

for( i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++)
   s.add(x[i] >= 1)
```

If not, what should be the most elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't write `expr x[100]` because the `expr` class does not have a constructor of the form `expr::expr()`. We should use the `expr_vector` instead. Here is an example (I also added it to the [official C++ example](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/157b5f0d9ce1a7618ce11f7708a72342bf5db55d) in the Z3 distribution).

```cpp
void expr_vector_example() {
    context c;
    const unsigned N = 10;

    expr_vector x(c);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        std::stringstream x_name; 
        x_name << "x_" << i;
        x.push_back(c.int_const(x_name.str().c_str()));
    }

    solver s(c);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        s.add(x[i] >= 1);
    }

    std::cout << s << "\n" << "solving...\n" << s.check() << "\n";
    model m = s.get_model();
    std::cout << "solution\n" << m;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I [added new C++ APIs](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/c8c5f30b49405fe2ae9bcd74021f84258f91ed5d) for creating universal and existential quantifiers using `expr_vector`.
The new APIs are already available in the `unstable` branch.
Here is an example:

```cpp
void exists_expr_vector_example() {
    std::cout << "exists expr_vector example\n";
    context c;
    const unsigned N = 10;

    expr_vector xs(c);
    expr x(c);
    expr b(c);
    b = c.bool_val(true); 

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        std::stringstream x_name; 
        x_name << "x_" << i;
        x = c.int_const(x_name.str().c_str());
        xs.push_back(x);
        b = b && x >= 0;
    }

    expr ex(c);
    ex = exists(xs, b);
    std::cout << ex << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! This is exactly what I was looking for. Also can this method be scaled for 2D arrays, so that we can have assertions of the form `s.add(x[i][j] >= 1);`

Comment: Yes, we can do it, but there is no `expr_matrix` in the C++ API. We have to use `std::vector<expr_vector>`. Note that, `expr_vector` is a more efficient version of `std::vector<expr>`. In `std::vector<expr>`, we have a vector of smart pointers, and each one of them has a reference to the context. In `expr_vector`, we have a vector of raw pointers and **one** reference to the context.

Comment: Also, using this method, can we encode expression like `forall( (x_1 Int) ... (x_10 Int) )((and (x_1 >0) ...(x_10 > 0) ))` without explicitly enumerating the variables.

Comment: I added a new feature to simplify this kind of construction (see update in the answer).