# Taking the address of a temporary object of type 'z3::expr'

Tags: c++, z3

I want to access the address of a `z3::expr` inside a `z3::expr_vector`.

```
z3::context ctx;
z3::expr_vector x(c);

// populate x with some push_backs ...

// access the address of the first element: 
z3::expr* t1 = &x[0]; // -Waddress-of-temporary: Taking the address of a temporary object 
                      // of type 'z3::expr'
```

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16418351/3418445), but that only talks about the `z3::expr`'s constructor.

If I use a `std::vector<z3_expr>` instead it works:

```
std::vector<z3::expr> x2;
...
z3::expr* t2 = &x2[0]; // This works
```

Is this intended, i.e. is the address not available to the user? Should I maintain an `std::vector<z3::expr>` instead?

Additionally, if I want to create a `z3::expr*` conditionally, how does go about it?

```
z3::expr* e;
if (some condition) {
    e = &(ctx.bv_const("s", 1)); // this gives the same compiler warning.
} else {
    e = &(ctx.bv_const("s", 1)); // as does this.
}

// use e
```

Some pointers regarding the correct usage would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z3::expr_vector` is a typedef for [`z3::ast_vector_tpl`](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1ast__vector__tpl.html), whose [`operator[]`](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1ast__vector__tpl.html#acc3b773e5965248fb65922197958e3a9) returns elements *by value*, ie a temporary *copy*.  So your `z3::expr_vector` example fails, because it is illegal to take the memory address of a temporary.

AFAICS, `ast_vector_tpl` does not have any methods that return access to its elements by reference/pointer, only by value.  Neither does its [`iterator`](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1ast__vector__tpl_1_1iterator.html) (so, something like `z3::expr* t1 = &*(x.begin());` would not work, either).

`std::vector`, on the other hand, has an [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) (and an `iterator` with an `operator*`) that returns access to its elements *by reference* instead, which is why your `std::vector` example works.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I'm a bit of a beginner in c++, sorry for the simple question, but from your link for `operator[]`,  how does one deduce that `operator[]` returns elements by value? i.e. which part of the code? Also, do let me know if you have any comments on the second part of the question as well.

Comment: "*how does one deduce that operator[] returns elements by value?*" - by the fact that `expr_vector` is a typedef for `z3::ast_vector_tpl<T>` where `T` is `z3::expr`,  and its `operator[]` returns a `T` (`z3::expr`) rather than a `T*` (`z3::expr*`) or `T&` (`z3::expr&`). "*do let me know if you have any comments on the second part of the question*" - AFAICS, it can't be done with `z3::expr_vector` at all, since there is no way to get a reference/pointer to an element, only a copy.

Comment: There's a good reason for why this cannot be done. Z3 internally uses reference counting to manage objects, and thus if you were allowed to take pointers to arbitrary elements you'd break internal variants and no doubt lead to core-dumps en-route. This is why a "copying" semantics is provided, but internally reference counting will take care of sharing and garbage collection.

Comment: In that case, use `z3::expr t1 = x[0];` instead. Or, in the latter example: `z3::expr e; if (some condition) { e = ctx.bv_const("s", 1); } else { e = ctx.bv_const("s", 1); } // use e`

Comment: Yep; that'd be the way to go. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'd also add, though tangential to the question, is that if you're new to C++, it's best *not* to program Z3 in C++. There're many other higher-level API's available (Java, Python, Haskell, O'Caml, Scala etc. included), which are much more programmer friendly. C++ should only be chosen if there's really a compelling reason, and the only one I can think of is building on top of existing infrastructure. ("Speed," for instance, is typically a non-reason: Most of the time will be spent in "solving," not in programming, for most applications. So it hardly matters what language you script z3 in.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RemyLebeau and @alias. @alias re: "a copying semantics is provided": what would be an alternative to using a pointer to a `z3::expr`?  Would using `Z3_get_ast_id` be a *correct* alternative? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741587/z3-significance-of-z3-get-ast-id )

Comment: Do not use a pointer to an expression. Simply take a copy, and z3 will manage it for you under the hood.